# The curvature of a line defined in terms of s

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, curvature, frenet-frame

I have a curve defined in terms of arclength $s$ :

$$ 
x=\arctan(s)
$$
$$ 
y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(s^2+1)
$$
$$
z=s-\arctan(s)
$$

So to compute its curvature, I started by writing its first and second derivatives (which are supposed to correspond to $\hat{T}$ and $\kappa \hat{N}$ as coordinates are directly expressed in terms of s) :
$$
\langle \frac{1}{(1+s^2)};\sqrt{2}s; \frac{s^2}{(1+s^2)} \rangle
$$
$$
\langle \frac{-2s}{(1+s^2)^2}; \sqrt{2}; \frac{-2s}{(1+s^2)^2} \rangle
$$
Now, $\kappa$ is supposed to be $\Vert \frac{d \hat{T}}{ds} \Vert$

And computing it I find :
$$
\sqrt{ \frac{8s^2+2(1+s^2)^4}{(1+s^2)^4}}
$$

BUT the textbook I use (Schaum's outline of vector analysis, problem 3.48) gives the answer :
$$
\kappa= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{s^2+1}
$$

They don't give the details of the computation...
What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I have this book and you have copied wrongly the equations of the curve. It is $y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(1+s^2)$.

Comment: @user326159 Thank you I corrected my mistake, but it does not change the derivative, does it?

Comment: No. However, does the module of the velocity of the curve is equal to $1$?

Comment: To restate the last question: Is the curve arclength-parametrized? You might want to download (and read) my differential geometry text. The link is in my profile.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin : thank you very much for the input, unfortunately, I'm still lost as it is stated in the question that the curve IS in fact arclength parametrized... am I still supposed to divide by the module? how come the module for the velocity is not 1 when it is supposed to be arclength parametrized? I'll read you text, but it seems to be a bit involved for my level : I'm trying to self teach basic vector calculus, I think your text will be a good resource for after I level up :)

Comment: There's a mistake, then. Since your velocity vector does not have length $1$, I suggest that the problem is flawed. Your computation isn't correct, regardless, since the velocity vector is not the unit tangent (and, moreover, the parameter $s$ is not in fact arclength).

Comment: P.S. if you take $y=\frac{\sqrt2}2 \ln(s^2+1)$, it will work out better, I suppose.

Comment: There is an error on the sign of the second derivative of $z=s-\arctan(s)$. However, because of the absolute value, this error has no impact on the computation of the curvature. Your computation is correct.